# Palette empty in NetBeans 7.2.1 on Windows XP

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ide, palette

I'm new to Java programming, I wanna develop small software for cell phones (Nokia Asha 200 at first). At first the Palette had some items, but as I downloaded Swing components, nothing is showing anymore. I already tried many solutions proposed over the net, but most of them are for Linux systems, and I'm using Windows XP. Nothing worked. The palette remains empty, although the menu Tools|Palette says it should have a lot of stuff (like Swing, AWT, Beans, etc). Someone said somewhere to right-click on the palette and choose "order by...", but right-clicking doesn't show any menu. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a "form" (`JPanel`) is fine.  Open the form in design view.  The palette should now have some content (as it is context sensitive).  If that fails, try uninstall and re-installing netbeans

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. Now the menu appears in the palette. The last option in it is Palette Manager, I guess (it's in portuguese, though I asked to download the english version!) Well, clicking on it, it lists only one item - Swing/AWT Components - with three subitems: "Appearances" (or Layout? empty), "Beans" (1 item) and "Java Persistence" (2 items). When I choose Tools|Palette|Swing/AWT Components, the tree has a lot of other stuff (5 Swing, 1 AWT and Borders), but clicking them won't show nothing new in the palette. Maybe it's something simple going on again?

Comment: Maybe this helps: in the code, there's a line "public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {" and it's saying "package javax.swing does not exist". I added "import javax.swing" and it says "package javax does not exist". I think the error is here. (Googling it now.)

Comment: In the palette manager, try selecting "Reset Palette" (last button on the right)

Comment: It should be `javax.swing.*` (just to be sure).  If the Swing package didn't exist, Netbeans wouldn't be running

Comment: I did it already, but nothing changed. It blinks new items as if trying to add them, but then they disappear very fast.

Comment: "import javax.swing.*;" -> "package javax.swing does not exist"

Comment: Maybe it's a compatibility issue? I installed NetBeans for JavaSE first. Then I found out I needed JavaME, uninstalled the first and installed the full version. Before that I had installed Nokia Developer Tools, which I'm not sure if is really necessary.

Comment: That is worrying, but as Netbeans is based on Swing, it must be installed somewhere.  Check you projects "Java Platform".  Right click the project node, select "Properties", select the "Libraries" node, first option

Comment: It's begin awhile, but I'm pretty sure ME doesn't have Swing

Comment: I was following this tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html and got to "Creating a MIDP/CLDC Application" step 6, but there was no Flow, nor Palette items like in the image. I'll sleep now, try again tomorrow. Thanks for your help.